# Is it good to use VR lens with teleconverter?

Tags: nikon, image-stabilization, teleconverter

I recently thinking to do something more for my photography experience. I want to buy a telephoto lens with a VR but it is expensive. That's why i am thinking that i should buy teleconverter instead because i already have my VR lens.

But, will the VR on my lens still be useful if i buy a teleconverter? 
I also want to know the other weakness of using VR with teleconverter thank u.

Comment: To get any meaningful answer you're going to need to tell us the lens you currently have, the teleconverter you are considering, and the other lens you are considering. What use cases you plan to shoot with either option would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VR (vibration reduction) built into a lens still works when that lens is used with a teleconverter.

The lens still creates a image.  The teleconverter takes that image and projects is larger onto the sensor, but that's a detail that doesn't really matter.  The VR system in the lens will still strive to keep the image the lens is forming stable, regardless of what is done to that image later.

One issue is that simply by enlarging the image, any motion will also be enlarged.  This is not because of the teleconverter itself, but simply as a result of the enlargement.  You would get the same increased apparent motion blur by making a larger print of a small area of a picture taken with the lens normally.

Answer (score 0):

VR is always good to use, Teleconverters are no exceptions.

TC's usually come as a 1.4x, 1.5x, 2x and whatnot.

FOR example : A 2x TC will increase your lens' focal length by two times along with reducing the aperture value by the same ratio i.e. a **f/4 will become a f/8, causing the light falling on the sensor to be reduced by 2 stops** ( 4 times less). To compensate for this loss in light, you will need to either bump up the ISO or use slower shutter speed.

using in-lens image stabilization will allow you to take photographs with lower shutter speeds, without blurring the image.

Nikon's VR claims to go 4 stops slower as compared to a non-VR lens, but that's  ideal case, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Using a teleconverter magnifies both your subject and any movement in your camera. That means chances of vibration is more even if your lens has a VR. So either you have to increase the shutter speed or use at least a mono pod. Focusing speed will be reduced. Using a tele convertor is a cheap way to get more focal length. But image quality, and speed of the actual lens will be reduced.